# Stable version of gevent?

Tags: python, pip, gevent

There appears to be a stable and unstable version here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gevent#downloads

It's not entirely clear to me what the distinctions are. I'm guessing there's a stable version on pip, described under the heading "Get gevent", and there's a separate unstable version on github under the heading "Development".

I simply want to install the stable version for production usage. `pip install gevent` doesn't seem to be the proper way to do this, since it installs something that has a syntax error in line 289 of `hub.py`, and looking in there I realized that it's a completely different version of gevent from the most up-to-date version on Github.

How do I install gevent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the current version on pypi is a release candidate and [*partially* supports Python 3](https://github.com/gevent/gevent/issues/38). If you want a stable version (that doesn't support python 3.x) you could try specifying the specific version when you invoke pip

```
pip install gevent==1.0.2
```

Alternately, you can install the version based on a specific commit on Github

```
pip install git+git://github.com/gevent/gevent.git#egg=gevent
```

This is what they are referring to as the development version. This means that you will be running the code as it exists on Github which could potentially be buggy but will include all latest changes to the codebase.

As a sidenote, if you're having issues with the version currently on pypi, you can see if the issues are reproducible using the most recent Github changes and submit a bug report to the developers.

Comment: Does release candidate imply stable enough for production, but not battle tested? I tried `pip install gevent==1.1rc3` and it worked, whereas gevent 1.0.2 was giving the SyntaxError. Also, does the second command using git require installing git?

Comment: Are you using python 3? If so, I believe that 1.1 is the first version to partially support python 3 hence the SyntaxError

Comment: Ah I see, that explains a lot. I am using python 3. Thank you! One more thing, do you know if 1.1rc3 is suitable for production use?

Comment: Checkout their changelog to determine if it is stable enough for your needs. https://github.com/gevent/gevent/blob/master/changelog.rst

Comment: The last comment in the conversation links to here, it actually looks pretty good: https://github.com/gevent/gevent/issues/38

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101125/discussion-between-suever-and-david-tan).